How to use a "chunk number" when collection is chunked
I am preparing to store xml based on a collection of objects.
Based on the size of the object-model to store, I will chunk these objects based on collection size in order to keep the memory footprint small.
Ex:
        val totalSum = someObjectCollection
            .asSequence()
            .chunked(<chunk size>)
            ...
            transform collection objects
            ...
            .storeObjectAsXml(it)
            .sumOf { it.sum }

As the example over demonstrates, the collection is first chunked, then the object model will undergo several transformations, before being stored as xml.
The function where I store the xml is done by http/ftp via. some channel and I cannot determine if the "chunk" stored is belonging to a bigger batch.
Ie. 90% of the stored xml will result in a filename like batch_00.xml, but 10% of the time, the batch will be chunked, and then I would like to generate the files batch_01.xml,batch_02.xml..batch_0x.xml according to chunks being stored.
Is there a way of sending the "chunk number" with the "chunked collection" being transformed or must I design the store-function to be able cont the number of stores being done at a specific point int time (every day or half a day)?
Any suggestions/examples?

The more readable solution will be to use the method .withIndex().
Ex
        val totalSum = someObjectCollection
            .asSequence()
            .chunked(<chunk size>)
            .withIndex()
            ...
            .map { <transform collection objects with IndexedValue>  }
            ...
            .storeChunkedObjectsAsXml(it) // it contains IndexValue.index
            .sumOf { indexed -> indexed.value.sumOf { it.sum } }


You still need a map here, it's not different from for each.

forEach { ... } is a Unit function and will not work to gather the information from .sumOf { ... }. What do you mean, need a map? the "transform collection objects with indexed value" should be a series of .map { ... } functions

How about something like using padStart :
fun storeObjectAsXml(chunk: List<SomeObject>, chunkNumber: Int) {
        val filename = "batch_${chunkNumber.toString().padStart(2, '0')}.xml"
        // Logic to store the chunk as XML using the filename
}
    
fun processAndStoreChunks(someObjectCollection: List<SomeObject>, chunkSize: Int) {
            var totalSum = 0
            someObjectCollection
                .asSequence()
                .chunked(chunkSize)
                .withIndex()
                .forEach { (index, chunk) ->
                    // Transform the chunk
                    val transformedChunk = chunk.map { transformObject(it) }
                    // Store the chunk as XML
                    storeObjectAsXml(transformedChunk, index)
                    // Update total sum
                    totalSum += transformedChunk.sumOf { it.someValue }
                }
            println("Total Sum: $totalSum")
        }
        
fun transformObject(obj: SomeObject): SomeTransformedObject {
            // Logic to transform the object
            return SomeTransformedObject(obj.someValue * 2) // Example transformation
}


I like the way of using padStart, but is there no other way of sending the index of the chunk? I feel this is not as readable and this will only look more complicated as I also have more than one transformObject-method

besides, I must also transfer some data across the chunks (ie. totalSum from the example)

Could you use withIndex() instead of forEachIndexed()?

@jactor-rises i update the answer. Could you please check again if this works for you ?

@gidds sorry, I do not want .forEach { ... } and I already added the solution for .withIndex()

@gidds then how are you going to loop through the collection of chunks ?
I am sorry but please be clear of what you want.

I have already created a solution based on the example solution above. It uses IndexedValue<List> which will undergo the transformation needed

In your description, you don’t mention anything summing, just about having a problem sending chunk number.
